# Weird glitch in path

Tags: mapbox, turfjs

I'm using Mapbox to create a path between Melbourne and Buenos Aires.
I use this example from Mapbox: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-route/

When I change the coordinates, it seems that there is an extra line, but I guess that's just because of the plain view of the map. Can I avoid this somehow?
You can see the issue here: https://codepen.io/zoltanseer/pen/NWbJExy

Code from codepen:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoiem9sdGFuc2VlciIsImEiOiJjanNjYjd4cWQwajkzNGJvYTd4Z3BuZGFtIn0.cDN0Zn4S1tbx8qWkFCxqBQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [144.96752, -37.81739],
    zoom: 3
});

// Melbourne
var origin = [144.96752, -37.81739];

// Buenos Aires
var destination = [-58.37344, -34.6085];

// A simple line from origin to destination.
var route = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [
        {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': [origin, destination]
            }
        }
    ]
};

// A single point that animates along the route.
// Coordinates are initially set to origin.
var point = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [
        {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'properties': {},
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': origin
            }
        }
    ]
};

// Calculate the distance in kilometers between route start/end point.
var lineDistance = turf.length(route.features[0]);

var arc = [];

// Number of steps to use in the arc and animation, more steps means
// a smoother arc and animation, but too many steps will result in a
// low frame rate
var steps = 500;

// Draw an arc between the `origin` & `destination` of the two points
for (var i = 0; i < lineDistance; i += lineDistance / steps) {
    var segment = turf.along(route.features[0], i);
    arc.push(segment.geometry.coordinates);
}

// Update the route with calculated arc coordinates
route.features[0].geometry.coordinates = arc;

// Used to increment the value of the point measurement against the route.
var counter = 0;

map.on('load', function () {
    // Add a source and layer displaying a point which will be animated in a circle.
    map.addSource('route', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': route
    });

    map.addSource('point', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': point
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'route',
        'source': 'route',
        'type': 'line',
        'paint': {
            'line-width': 2,
            'line-color': '#007cbf'
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'point',
        'source': 'point',
        'type': 'symbol',
        'layout': {
            'icon-image': 'airport-15',
            'icon-rotate': ['get', 'bearing'],
            'icon-rotation-alignment': 'map',
            'icon-allow-overlap': true,
            'icon-ignore-placement': true
        }
    });

    function animate() {
        var start =
            route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
                counter >= steps ? counter - 1 : counter
            ];
        var end =
            route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[
                counter >= steps ? counter : counter + 1
            ];
        if (!start || !end) return;

        // Update point geometry to a new position based on counter denoting
        // the index to access the arc
        point.features[0].geometry.coordinates =
            route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[counter];

        // Calculate the bearing to ensure the icon is rotated to match the route arc
        // The bearing is calculated between the current point and the next point, except
        // at the end of the arc, which uses the previous point and the current point
        point.features[0].properties.bearing = turf.bearing(
            turf.point(start),
            turf.point(end)
        );

        // Update the source with this new data
        map.getSource('point').setData(point);

        // Request the next frame of animation as long as the end has not been reached
        if (counter < steps) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    document
        .getElementById('replay')
        .addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Set the coordinates of the original point back to origin
            point.features[0].geometry.coordinates = origin;

            // Update the source layer
            map.getSource('point').setData(point);

            // Reset the counter
            counter = 0;

            // Restart the animation
            animate(counter);
        });

    // Start the animation
    animate(counter);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that using `turf.greatCircle()` solves the issue.